# A question in the proof of equivalence of Cech cohomology and Sheaf cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

While proving the equivalence of Sheaf cohomology (defined by using injective resolutions), Tennison (in his book 'Sheaf Theory' on page 146) says :

> If we let $S$ be a presheaf such that the sequence $ 0 \to R' \to R \to S \to 0 $ is exact in Presh/X, we see that $S$ has as sheafification the zero sheaf and there is an exact sequence < long exact sequence corresponding to the above short exxact sequence>.

Here $R' \to R$ is the sheafification map of the presheaf $R'$. I can understand that $S$ can be shosen to be the Presheaf cokernel of the sheafification map. My question is : **But how do we know that this map is exact at $R'$** ? 
Edit : As pointed out in the comment, this need not be exact at $R'$. So the question is : How do we tweak the proof in the book so that it becomes valid ?

Comment: Unless $R^\prime$ is separated, meaning that two sections over an open which agree on some covering of that open must be the same, the map from $R^\prime$ to its sheafification will not be injective.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Thanks. That is right, I have edited the question to ask : how do we tweak the proof in the book then ?

Comment: You could consider instead the short exact sequences $0\to \text{ker}(s)\to R^{\prime}\to \text{im}(s)\to 0$ and $0\to \text{im}(s)\to R\to\text{coker}(s)\to 0$ where $s: R^{\prime}\to R$ is the sheafification map, using that the sheafifications of $\text{ker}(s)$ and $\text{coker}(s)$ vanish.